# CSS Drop-shadow errantly applying to <img> container in some places instead of the <img> element

Tags: html, css

Solved! See answer below.

---

I am building a website which has multiple `<section>` elements. In most of the `<section>` elements, I am able to properly apply a CSS `filter: drop-shadow` rule to a given `<img>` element by giving it an `id` in the HTML and then specifying that `id` in the CSS and giving it a rule like `filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 5px black);`.

However, in one `<section>` on the page, when I do the above method to apply a drop-shadow to images within that section, the drop-shadow is applied to the individual containing `<div>` elements, instead of the `<img>` elements themselves.

The HTML of the section in question is:

```
<section class="skills" id="skills">
      <h2 class="skill-header">Skills</h2>

      <div class="skills-wrapper">
        <div class="icon-wrapper">
          <img
            src="./assets/memojis/Me-Memoji-wondering-flipped.png"
            alt="Me wondering memoji"
            loading="lazy"
            class="icon icon-card skills-memoji"/>
        </div>
        <div class="icon-wrapper">
          <img
            src="./assets/icons/icons8-html-5.svg"
            alt=""
            loading="lazy"
            class="icon icon-card"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="icon-wrapper">
          <img
            src="assets/icons/icons8-css3.svg"
            alt=""
            loading="lazy"
            class="icon icon-card"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="skills-wrapper">
        <div class="icon-wrapper">
          <img
            src="assets/icons/icons8-javascript.svg"
            alt=""
            loading="lazy"
            class="icon icon-card"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="icon-wrapper">
          <img
            src="assets/icons/icons8-bootstrap.svg"
            alt=""
            loading="lazy"
            class="icon icon-card"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="icon-wrapper">
          <img
            src="./assets/memojis/Me-Memoji-thumbs-upping.png"
            alt="Me giving a thumbs up"
            loading="lazy"
            class="icon icon-card skills-memoji"
          />
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
```

The CSS is:

```
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  background-color: var(--color-background);
  /* background-image: url("./background.svg"); */
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  color: var(--color-text);
  text-shadow: var(--text-shadow);
}

.skills {
  align-items: center;
  margin: var(--margin-section-standard);
  max-width: var(--section-max-width);
  width: var(--section-width);
  background-color: var(--color-section);
  border-radius: var(--border-radius-right-trapezoid-large);
  padding: var(--padding-section-standard);
  border: var(--border);
  box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
  scroll-margin-block-start: var(--scroll-margin-block-start);
}

.skills h2 {
  margin-bottom: var(--bottom-margin-1);
  text-align: center;
}

.skills div {
  line-height: var(--line-height);
  padding: 0.4rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.skills .skills-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
}

.icon-wrapper {
  display: inline-grid;
  width: 20%;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 1rem;
}

.icon {
  filter: var(--drop-shadow-image);
}

.icon-card {
  background-color: var(--color-background);
  border-radius: var(--border-radius-right-trapezoid-small);
  box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
  padding: 1rem;
  /* margin: 10px; */
  width: 12rem;
  border: var(--border);
}

.skills-memoji {
  /* filter: var(--drop-shadow-image); */
}
```

When I un-comment the `filter` rule in the `.skills-memoji` ruleset in order to make it active, the drop-shadow is applied to the containing element of class `.icon-wrapper`. I am trying to figure out how to get the drop-shadow to apply to the actual `<img>` elements in the HTML, as specified in the CSS by their class `.skills-memoji`.

Answer (score 1):

Solved! I had the background-color and border stylings set on the .icon-card class, which is at the same hierarchical level as the .skills-memoji class that I was trying to get the filter: drop-shadow() set on. I guess that was causing the browser to compute that the elements classed as .skills-memoji had a background-color spec and border spec, causing the image to be viewed as having a non-transparent background (plus border), which caused the browser to render the filter: drop-shadow() on the edge of the background of .skills-memoji instead of directly on the  elements.

I moved the background-color and border specs to be on the div classed .icon-wrapper, containing each div classed .icon-card. Once I made that change, those two  elements rendered as I had been expecting them to previously.